# Dynamically Add/Remove columns from dropdown angularjs

Tags: angularjs

if i click remove column name that column has to remove from table and also the columns that are not listed in table  has to be in add column

like Remove column there will other Add column  and also save button.

[image]

Comment: maintain an array with name of columns and update it as per your needs to add and remove columns and in table put `<td ng-repeat="col in columns">{{col}}</td>` for header and for data use `<tr ng-repeat="row in rows"><td ng-repeat="col in columns">{{data['col']}}</td></tr>`

Comment: then it will display all heading in array

Comment: once check above image

Comment: ok wait a min, will create a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the plunkr. You can add or remove the column in the array maintained inside the controller to update your table.

https://plnkr.co/edit/w90MlA?p=preview

**HTML -**

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="demoCtrl">

    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ng-repeat="col in cols">{{col}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
          <td ng-repeat="col in cols">
            {{row[col]}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JS -**

```
// Code goes here

var demoApp = angular.module("demoApp", []);

demoApp.controller("demoCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.cols = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  $scope.rows = [
  {
    'A': "1", 
    'B': "2",
    'C': "3",
    'D': "4"
  },
  {
    'A': "5", 
    'B': "6",
    'C': "7",
    'D': "8"
  },
  {
    'A': "11", 
    'B': "21",
    'C': "31",
    'D': "41"
  }
  ]
}]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks ,i want like i have like 10 column name in list ,by default i will show 5 columns ,above of table there will be preferences dropdown in that there will be add column  ,remove column and save .i add column there remaining column names from the list will display .in remove column the column names those are displaying on table has to be there

Comment: if u remove column name from preferences-->remove column -->column name then that removed  column name has to add to preference->add Column(dropdown)

Comment: instead of that search box .i want to add some pre defined columns names to that add button as dropdown

Comment: I think that you can figure out by yourself.

Comment: once check above image preference-->remove column--->(list)

Comment: Well I had a look and I think you should be able to figure it out by yourself now... if you have little idea of angular. I am not here to write whole code for you.

Comment: Till now what ever you told ,i am already done with those things.again u told the same thing.Thank you for your response

Comment: Put your code here or modify plunkr as per your need and let me know where are you facing issues.

Comment: So whats the issue?

Comment: now onclick add it is adding new columns in sequence but i want those in dropdown,so that i can decide which column i want to add

Comment: I think you got to learn angular first before coming here...refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion